# Temporarily changing a variable in python based of a button being pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

Part of a game i'm trying to make is that if you lose, (ball.hit_bottom == True) an end screen comes up with your score. I also have buttons to return the user to the home screen. However, due to how i've built it ball.hit_bottom remains true so as soon as the button to return the player to the home screen is clicked, it updates and the screen in ball.hit_bottom loads. I don't understand how to stop this happening.

I'm trying to get it so that when the button is pressed, it runs MenuReturn and goes back to homepage so they can start again or choose a different game.

Sorry if this is badly done, i'm new to this.

STARTUPTWO() brings up the home page. This works, but only for a tiny amount of time before reverting back to the end screen.

```
def MenuReturn():
    startup = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('Return To Menu','Are you sure?')
    if startup == True:
        STARTUPTWO() 
        y = 0
    else:
        tk.destroy() 

y=1

while y:

    timeforscore+=1 
    if timeforscore ==100:
        timeforscore =1
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01) 

    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw() 
        paddle.draw() 
    if ball.hit_bottom == True:
        canvas.delete(ALL)
        canvas.create_text(350, 160, font=("Bauhaus 93",30), fill = 'Red', text='Unlucky! You lost with a final score of...')
        txtpad1score = canvas.create_text(350, 350, font=("Bauhaus 93",60), fill = 'Red', text='0') 

        btnmenufor = Button(text = "Menu", command = MenuReturn, anchor = W)
        btnmenufor.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5")
        btnmenufor_window =  canvas.create_window(300, 670, anchor=NW, window=btnmenufor)
```

Comment: Did you try to make `ball.hit_bottom = False` after `if startup == True:` and before `STARTUPTWO()`?

Comment: For some reason that doesn't make a difference. It goes back to the home screen when clicked, but instantly goes back to the end game screen as it did before.

Comment: Ahhh I think you should make `y = 0` before `STARTUPTWO()`. It's trapped inside the the looping. That's my best guess given what I know about your program :(

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: I think it's cos y still = 1, even if i have a y=0 before it